# Dialogflow don't recognize/match the input with the proper intent, whats the problem?

Tags: dialogflow-es

My knowledge of programming is very basic. And i'm having troubles for dialogflow give answers properly, it was working just fine a few days ago but now for some intents (1-2 at the moment) it dont recognizes an clear input and get on fallback intent all the times.